# Delete duplicates based on submission date?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet with employee records, and I have 150,000 rows. Columns A-D have employee info (Employee ID, First Name, Last Name, Job Title)

`Column E` is Hire date, `Column F` contains text strings.

Say rows 2-5 are all from the same employee, different hire dates, but every row in column F = `Negative`

Is there a `Countif` formula that can place the string, "Keep" in the row with the earliest hire date for that employee and place "Remove" the for the duplicate rows for that employee?

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A$2:A2,A2,D$2:D2,D2)>1,"Mark","")
```

that I used for finding just duplicates while comparing two columns and wondered if I could repurpose it fit these needs.

something like `=IF(COUNTIFS(A$1:A1,A1,D$1:D1,D1)>1,"Keep","Remove")` but also add in a feature to base that by earliest date so it knows what to keep. Maybe that can be done just by ordering the date by a-z?

Comment: What version of excel do you have? See if you have the function `MINIFS()` available to you

Comment: I have version 2013. I just have like 3 different types of Value matching scenarios that could be made into if statements. Should I edit my question to incorporate those?

Answer (score 0):

## MIN vs MATCH

In any solution replace 21 with the last row number e.g. 150000.

### MIN Solution

For a cell in the second row, copy the following **array formula** into the Formula bar and hold `LEFT CTRL SHIFT` and press `ENTER`.

> ```
> =IF(MIN((A$2:A$21=A2)*B$2:B$21)=B2,"Keep","Remove")
> ```

and copy down.

[image]

---

### MATCH Solution ('Partly Sorted')

If the Employee ID is unique for each employee and the list is 'partly sorted' by hire date i.e. the first appearance of an employee contains the lowest date, in the second row you can use the formula:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2,A$1:A1,0)),"Remove","Keep")
```

and copy down.

[image]